# Optional lookahead in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to build a regex for a user input. Im building a form based on the user Input. Lets assume that the user assigns the css property as to "Icon-[anything]" (Bootstrap Icon). Now in this case i have to ensure that "--" is not repeated more than once and also should ensure that "icon-white" should be the only class assigned beside the other one; this 'icon-white' has to optional as well.

```
/^icon-[a-z-]+(\ icon-white)?$/
```

- this regex works fine for the OPTIONAL Icon-white Scenario, but having some issue in avoiding the repetition of '--'.

Comment: What is the lookahead supposed to do here? Currently, it checks whether the string, that is matched by `icon-[a-z-]+`, is followed by `icon-white`.

Comment: Yes and i want the icon-white to be optional

Comment: As with all regex questions, you need to clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do. Give example targets that should be matched (with explanations of _why_ for each), and targets that would not be matched (again, with explanations).  Also, remember that there are regex experts here who can help, but may not have any knowledge of bootstrap - so if you phrase your question to avoid assumed knowledge about bootstrap, you'd get more input.

Comment: What is the point of an optional lookahead? _I want to match __a__ if it is followed by __b__ but also if it isn't_. Isn't that just __a__?

Comment: @Sepster: Roger that, thank you brother.

Comment: @ZiaudDeen My pleasure mate.  But your spec is still way too vague, but I've had a crack at it for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match "icon-somevalue" but not "icon-white" try

```
icon-(?!white).*
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (although I'm not sure I do, sorry...) I think you're saying that the following two scenarios are allowed:

1. `icon-white`
2. `icon-[anything]` where `[anything]` can be any lower-case text and include a hyphen, but never two (or more) hyphens directly next to each other like `--`.

You've not said *where* this pattern might occur, although your original regex suggests this pattern will occur anchored to the start of your test string, so I'll assume that's the case.  In which case, this regex should help:

**`^icon-white$|^icon-([a-z]+-?)+$`**

Breaking that down:

1. `^icon-white$` Match the literal string that contains *exactly* "icon-white"
2. `|` or
3. `^icon-([a-z]+-?)+$` Match the literal string that *starts with exactly* "icon-" and then *immediately ends with* "something" which is `([a-z]+-?)+`.

Now, to be clear - I don't get the relationship between `icon-white` and `icon-[something]`.  That is, as far as I see it there's no reason why the `icon-[something]` pattern at 3 above can't cover the "icon-white" literal too.  ie 1 and 2 above are redundant.  But I've included them here so you can maybe piece something more suitable together.

Breaking that "something" down from 3:

1. `(    )+` means one or more instances of whatever's inside the parenthesis, which is `[a-z]+-?`

Breaking that `[a-z]+-?` down:

1. `[a-z]+` At least one character "a" through "z" (note hyphen is NOT allowed here to avoid additional hyphen immediately after the previous one)
2. `-?`  An optional hyphen (ie exactly 0 or 1 hyphen)

---

This matches the following test cases:

1. icon-white
2. icon-x
3. icon-xx
4. icon-x-
5. icon-xx-
6. icon-x-x
7. icon-xx-x
8. icon-xx-xx
9. icon-x-x-x-
10. icon-x-xx-xx-x-xxxxx-
    ... and so on

This DOES NOT match the following test cases:

1. any case where a capital letter used (you've specified only lower-case)
2. icon- (because we need *one or more* characters for "something".
3. icon--
4. icon--x
5. icon-x--

---

I hope this covers your needs, but I doubt it does (because I didn't really understand your explanation "ensure that "icon-white" should be the only class assigned beside the other one"), but hopefully my breakdown will give you the pieces you need.

---

**EDIT:**

I think maybe you're saying the scenarios allowed are:

1. icon-[something]
2. icon-[something] icon-white
3. icon-white icon-[something]

where [something] is any combinations of lower-case text and hypens, so long as there's never a double-hyphen, and so long as it's not "white".

So... this defines "icon-[something]" : `icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+`

This means our 3 above scenarios are:

1. `^icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+$`
2. `^icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+ icon-white$`
3. `^icon-white icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+$`

And hence, putting it all together:

**`^icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+$|^icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+ icon-white$|^icon-white icon-(?!white$)([a-z]+-?)+$`**

I tried doing this with the icon-white section as an optional group, but had trouble with the negative lookahead from the first section capturing it... so... this'll do ;-)